# How to download multiple files with different names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sitemap, sitemap.xml

```
df = pandas.read_excel('path of file')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #row name where excel data exist
    Url=row['Row Name']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--iocp' in sys.argv:
        from asyncio import events, windows_events
        sys.argv.remove('--iocp')
        logging.info('using iocp')
        el = windows_events.ProactorEventLoop()
        events.set_event_loop(el)
    #storing name    
    crawler(Url, out_file='sitemap.xml')
```

I want to **download multiple files** with **different file name** as given file name is **sitemap.xml**

```
crawler(Url, out_file='sitemap.xml')
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it seems like you want `crawler` to run for each iteration of the `for` loop, no?

Comment: @wkl yes, now I want file to download with different name